# Get parent with more than 2 child

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure:

```
| id | parent |
   1     0
   2     1
   3     1
   4     2
   5     2
   6     2
```

How can I get the id of the parent row that have more than 2 childs ?
(in the above case should return only the *id=2* row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is enough to find the parent id

```
SELECT parent
FROM   tablename
GROUP  BY parent
HAVING Count(parent) > 2
```

Comment: This isn't enough actually. This is return 1 record instead of 3 records.

Comment: Then what about this *(in the above case should return only the id=2 row)*

Comment: Return 3 records with the id=2. I am not sure what's op need. But, I guess op need to return all records with id=2.

Comment: @RubahMalam - He wants id not the parent id. So he don't need 3 rows

Comment: Yeap @Indian I only need the id of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename 
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT parent
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY parent
    HAVING COUNT(parent) > 2
)
```